# Python: Can't start new thread. Can I stagger or delay some threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping

Not really sure how to ask this question since I am just beginning to learn python but here it goes:

I have a web **scraper** that uses threading to grab info. I am looking for pricing and stock for about 900 products. When I test the script with about half of that, there is no problem. When I try to **scrape** all 900 products I get a can't start new thread error.

I imagine this is do to some memory constraint or it is because I am asking a server for too many requests

I would like to know if there is a way to slow down the threads or to stagger the requests.

Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\tests\dxpriceupdates.py", line 78, in <module>
    t.start()
error: can't start new thread
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):Exception in thread Thread-554:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 346, in open_http
    errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1117, in getreply
    response = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 441, in begin
    self.msg = HTTPMessage(self.fp, 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetools.py", line 25, in __init__
    rfc822.Message.__init__(self, fp, seekable)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\rfc822.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.readheaders()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 308, in readheaders
    self.addheader(headerseen, line[len(headerseen)+1:].strip())
MemoryError

<bound method Thread.__bootstrap of <Thread(Thread-221, stopped 9512)>>Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):

Traceback (most recent call last):
Unhandled exception in thread started by Unhandled exception in thread started by ...
```

Here is the python (The skulist.txt is just a text file like 12345, 23445, 5551,...):

```
from threading import Thread
import urllib
import re
import json
import math    

def th(ur):
    site = "http://dx.com/p/GetProductInfoRealTime?skus="+ur
    htmltext = urllib.urlopen(site)
    data = json.load(htmltext)
    htmlrates = urllib.urlopen("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=AUD")
    datarates = json.load(htmlrates)
    if data['success'] == True:
        if data['data'][0]['discount'] is 0:
            price = float(data['data'][0]['price'])
            rate = float(datarates['rate']) + 0.12
            cost = price*rate
            if cost <= 5:
                saleprice = math.ceil(cost*1.7) - .05
            elif (cost >5) and (cost <= 10):
                saleprice = math.ceil(cost*1.6) - .05
            elif (cost >10) and (cost <= 15):
                saleprice = math.ceil(cost*1.55) - .05
            else:
                saleprice = math.ceil(cost*1.5) - .05
            if data['data'][0]['issoldout']:
                soldout = "Out Of Stock"
                enabled = "Disable"
                qty = "0"
            else:
                soldout = "In Stock"
                enabled = "Enabled"
                qty = "9999"
            
            #print model, saleprice, soldout, qty, enabled
            myfile.write(str(ur)+","+str(saleprice)+","+str(soldout)+","+str(qty)+","+str(enabled)+"\n")
        else:
            price = float(data['data'][0]['listprice'])
            rate = float(datarates['rate']) + 0.12
            cost = price*rate
            if cost <= 5:
                saleprice = math.ceil(cost*1.7) - .05
            elif (cost >5) and (cost <= 10):
                saleprice = math.ceil(cost*1.6) - .05
            elif (cost >10) and (cost <= 15):
                saleprice = math.ceil(cost*1.55) - .05
            else:
                saleprice = math.ceil(cost*1.5) - .05
            if data['data'][0]['issoldout']:
                soldout = "Out Of Stock"
                enabled = "Disable"
                qty = "0"
            else:
                soldout = "In Stock"
                enabled = "Enabled"
                qty = "9999"
           
            #print model, saleprice, soldout, qty, enabled
            myfile.write(str(ur)+","+str(saleprice)+","+str(soldout)+","+str(qty)+","+str(enabled)+"\n")
    else:
        qty = "0"
        print ur, "error \n"
        myfile.write(str(ur)+","+"0.00"+","+"Out Of Stock"+","+str(qty)+","+"Disable\n")
         

skulist = open("skulist.txt").read()
skulist = skulist.replace(" ", "").split(",")

myfile = open("prices/price_update.txt", "w+")
myfile.close()

myfile = open("prices/price_update.txt", "a")
threadlist = []

for u in skulist:
    t = Thread(target=th,args=(u,))
    t.start()
    threadlist.append(t)

for b in threadlist:
    b.join()
  
myfile.close()
```

Comment: That's an abuse of threads .. search for "thread pool". There is usually little point to schedule many more threads than physical threading cores - I find 2x is generally "a good starting choice".

Comment: There is often much point in raising many more threads than physical threading cores.  Blocking I/O is a prime example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't fire 900 threads at once, your PC could literally choke! Instead, use a pool and distribute the activity on a certain number of workers. Use `multiprocessing` like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

WORKERS = 10
p = Pool(WORKERS)
p.map(tr, skulist)
```

Find the right value for `WORKERS` by experimenting a bit.

Comment: Yes,  use a large threadpool and a flow-controlled set of PriceGrabber tasks.